# dynamic streaming file format

Tags: python, web-scraping, streaming, kodi

is there any streaming file format that works like this :

1. make an http post or get
2. scrap html source
3. get the url
4. play

what i can do with python so far is this :

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess

# make request with requests  
# scraping with BeautifulSoup
# get the url (url = http://streamsource)

# play it via media player classic
MPC_path = '\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc.exe'
video_path = url
subprocess.call([MPC_path, video_path])
```

but is there a file format that is supported in **kodi/xbmc** and created to do this kind of work?

Unlike M3U, that uses the url directly

Comment: I don't have th answer but this site might help:
http://kodi.wiki/view/Python_development
also have a look at the site it points to:
http://mirrors.kodi.tv/docs/python-docs/16.x-jarvis/xbmc.html

Comment: @SSchneid thank you for your comment but that didnt answer my question